# Problem upgrading to 20.04 from 16.04

Tags: 20.04

Trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 20.04 and I get this message:

Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

This was likely caused by:

- Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
  Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge
  package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and
  try the upgrade again.

Can someone tell me what I need to do, please?  Thanks

Dell Latitude E6420  64-bit  8Gb  500 Gb SSD

Comment: Did you carefully uninstall all non-official software as the error message advised?

Comment: You cannot upgrade directly to 20.04 from 16.04. First you have to upgrade to 18.04. However, the error message indicates that you have some PPAs not supported in 18.04(?). Search in AskUbuntu on how to remove old PPAs.

Comment: you can download and install 20.4 LTS with USB from https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/

Comment: i dont have any deitels about that and if you have question about that please search it in internet